# Clearing an auto complete search and appending value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have done an auto complete such that when I click the selected result it appends to a div.

[image when picking a vehicle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8HPi.png)

But when I navigate away from that popup and return to it. When I do a search and click the result I want, it appends two values at a go with the second one as empty like in the next image.

[the second image with a blank value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mDDB.png)

How do I prevent this from happening ?

My code is as shown below:

```
 $(function(){
    $(".search1").keyup(function() { 
    var searchid = $(this).val();
    var dataString = 'search='+ searchid;
    if(searchid!=''){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "assets/ajax/search1.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $(".resultgeter").html(html).show();
            }
        });
    }return false;    
    });

    $(document).on('click', ".showing" , function() {
        var vhlid = $(this).html();
        $(".searchid").append('<div class="choice"><div class="pickVehicle">'+vhlid+'</div><div class="select2-search-choice-close"></div></div>');
        $(this).html("");
        this.html = "";
        $(this).remove();
        $(".resultgeter").fadeOut();
        return false;
    });
    $('.search1').click(function(){
        $(".resultgeter").fadeIn();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: could you provide your HTML?

Comment: You are click event is triggering twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the real solution for this, but a trick might work.
Adding an `if` statement to make sure `vhlid` is not blank while appending.

```
$(document).on('click', ".showing" , function() {
    var vhlid = $(this).html();
    if(vhlid!=" " || vhlid.length>1) {
        $(".searchid").append('<div class="choice"><div class="pickVehicle">'+vhlid+'</div><div class="select2-search-choice-close"></div></div>');
    }
    $(this).html("");
    this.html = "";
    $(this).remove();
    $(".resultgeter").fadeOut();
    return false;
});
```